# Getting even component of a signal in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

We know that even component of a signal can be found out by following formula

**Xeven=0.5(Xoriginal+Xreflected)**

How we can do it in MATLAB?

Forexample if **Xoriginal=tsin(πt)**;
and t=0:5

Comment: “How we can do it in MATLAB?” What does the “it” refer to? Reflecting the signal? Adding two signals? Multiplying by 0.5? By showing your attempt, we can more clearly see where the difficulty lies for you.

Comment: @CrisLuengo  reflecting the signal?

Comment: Your other question asks about reflecting the signal. If that is what you are after with this question,  then it’s a duplicate of that one. Please don’t post a duplicate question just because you’re not getting an answer fast enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to obtain folded/reflected signal in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55035773/how-to-obtain-folded-reflected-signal-in-matlab)